# Does Firebase Realtime .once() still download the entire node, when .keepSynced(true)?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to reconcile two seemingly conflicting sources of information from Google.

In the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) they say that 'value' from `.once()` is downloaded in full.

But [here](https://medium.com/p/c609b52b9afb/responses/show) in a fascinating post from a Firebase expert at Google, Frank van Puffelen, he says that `.keepSynced(true)` uses 'delta-sync' to only sync the parts which have changed.

In this case, if I set `keepSynced(true)`, and then call `.once()` on this same node, presumably it is not downloading the entire 'value' , only what has changed - is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `once()` you will get the value as it is currently cached.

If on the same node you called `keepSynced(true)` the value in the cache should be up to date with the server.

By using the combination of both, there won't be a client-to-server call per `once()` call, but there will still be client-to-server call when the app starts (to attach the implicit listener of `keepSynced(true)`) and a server-to-client push whenever the data changes.

It sounds like you're trying to work around a problem, instead of addressing it head on though: if data can change, you should use `on()` listeners instead of `once()`.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you so much for your personal reply. This information is invaluable to me, coming from the source. 

In case you are interested, I am effectively using realtime as a sole database, without any other local database in support. It works beautifully and for my purposes is much cleaner than SQLlite. 

I use a listener for onValue. But when I change data  which I require to be updated instantly, the listener does not fire fast enough to truly replace a local database. For these types of events I use once() to quickly refresh the local data snapshot.

Comment: Hi, if you're still there, could you possibly clarify something. Do i need to set keepSynced(true) each time app opens, does doing so reduce data, or waste any data? I have persistence enabled.

Comment: Setting `keepSynced()` is a transient operation (i.e. it is not persisted when the app restarts), so indeed needs to be called each time the app runs. Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a node will keep that node updated while the app is active. If there are more updates than you app needs, you will retrieve more data from the server when using `keepSynced(true)` then when only using listeners. You'll have to trade off data "freshness" against bandwidth usage.